Handling evolving Pydantic schema changes in FastAPI unit tests
I'm developing a production application using FastAPI where the API response schemas are frequently changing due to stakeholder requirements. The app is nearing production, and we have comprehensive unit tests in place.
Our testing framework consists of:

Unit tests using pytest
Two static files:

expected_outputs.json: Contains expected API responses
mock_inputs.json: Contains test input data


Tests that compare mocked FastAPI client responses against expected outputs

The problem is, as stakeholders regularly request new fields to be added to our API responses, our unit tests keep breaking because the JSON responses no longer match the expected outputs defined in our test files. While we can remove obsolete schemas, I'm questioning whether maintaining these unit tests is worthwhile given the constantly evolving schema.
Here's a simplified version of our current testing approach:
from pydantic import BaseModel
from fastapi import FastAPI
from typing import Optional

class UserCreate(BaseModel):
    username: str
    email: str

class User(UserCreate):
    id: int

app = FastAPI()

@app.post("/users/", response_model=User)
async def create_user(user: UserCreate):
    # Simplified example
    return User(id=1, **user.model_dump())

# Original test
def test_create_user(client):
## In our real code we are referring to the objects in the mock_inputs.json
    response = client.post("/users/", json={
        "username": "john_doe",
        "email": "john@example.com"
    })
    assert response.status_code == 200
## In our real code we are asserting to the objects in the expected_outputs.json
    assert response.json() == {
        "id": 1,
        "username": "john_doe",
        "email": "john@example.com"
    }
    assert response.json()['id'] == 1
...
    assert response.json()['email'] == "john@example.com"


Then a new field is added, for example full_name, the test would also have to be modified:
class UserCreate(BaseModel):
    username: str
    email: str
    full_name: Optional[str] = None
    phone: Optional[str] = None

# Original test
def test_create_user(client):
## In our real code we are referring to the objects in the mock_inputs.json
    response = client.post("/users/", json={
        "username": "john_doe",
        "email": "john@example.com"
    })
    assert response.status_code == 200
## In our real code we are asserting to the objects in the expected_outputs.json
    assert response.json() == {
        "id": 1,
        "username": "john_doe",
        "email": "john@example.com"
        "full_name": "John Locke"
    }
    assert response.json()['id'] == 1
...
    assert response.json()['full_name'] == "John Locke" ## Added new test for some key


Right now, we are adding the new fields (and sometimes remove old fields if they require us to do so) to the expected outputs and mock inputs, but this is hard to maintain since we will have to add these expected outputs and mock inputs for quite a lot of endpoints, since there are instances where there are tens of new fields being added.
Also good to mention, the schemas in question are also rather big 25++ fields on average per schema and we would like to test multiple scenarios, such as values being null (assuming a field can be optionally None) and then different data types as well.

This is the issue with using golden files as the determined output, instead of comparing the specific keys that your tests should validate - if the tests gets in the way of development, the expected format is either too restrictive (i.e. the test should validate what they actually test, not the general output format) - but in any case, new tests should probably cover the new fields anyway, so there will always be some new tests to write. I'm not fond of brittle tests that break because of unrelated changes, but this question will be mainly down to opinion. Try to narrow the tests and add more.
